# Recording processes spawned when running a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I currently have an issue whilst running a shell script in UNIX which would be easily solved if I could record the processes which are spawned during a run of my script. I'd thought to use the `top` command and record to a file e.g.

> ```
> top > tmp.txt
> ```

I think this would not be applicable however as it only refreshes periodically. Does anybody know how this would be possible? Ideally it would be something like this:

```
    pid:123 my_script.sh   
      pid:124 grep...   
        pid:125 ...
      pid:126 ...
```

You get the idea.

Kind Regards,

JLove

Answer (score 0):

Top has a "batch mode", which will send the latest "top" results to standard output.

You can do something like this:

```
top -bn3
```

Which will print the top results three times to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to know the pids of all processes that have your shell script as an ancestor.  `ps --forest` or `pstree` should give you what you need.